How to prevent liquid code displaying on front end
I am using [% include = 'ccss.css' %] to inject critical CSS into a Maropost site head section.
This Works fine except the liquid code is now rendered in the page front end header.
Is there an effective way to prevent the code rendering on front end? Thanks!!!
I've tried to use comment:
< {%- comment -%} {% include 'ccss.css' %}

{%- This is a comment that will not be visible in the front-end output. -%}

{%- endcomment -%} />
Made no difference, code still visible in header.
